# OOP circular reference

Tags: java, oop

I have a dilemma here about what is and what is not a circular reference... and how to get rid of it in affirmative case.

Let's say I have a `Main` class that instantiates two different classes where each of these classes need to execute a method in the other:

```
MyMain {
    AlarmManager alarmManager;
    DatabaseManager databaseManager;

    MyMain() {
        alarmManager = new AlarmManager(dataBaseManager);
        databaseManager = new DatabaseManager (alarmManager);
    }

    AlarmManager getAlarmManager() {
        return alarmManager;
    }

    DatabaseManager getDatabasetManager() {
        return databaseManager;
    }
}
```

And the classes:

```
AlarmManager {
    DatabaseManager dataBaseManager;

    onAlarm(alarm) {
        dataBaseManager.saveInHistorical(alarm);
        sendAlarm(alarm);
    }

    sendAlarm(alarm) {
        socketWriter(alarm);
    }
}

DatabaseManager{
    AlarmManager alarmManager;

    onDatabaseConnectionError() {
        saveInHistorical(databaseAlarm);
        alarmManager.sendAlarm(databaseAlarm);
    }

    saveInHistorical(historical) {
        connection.store(historical);
    }
}
```

I suppose you get the idea by looking at the code. If there's an alarm we receive it in the AlarmManager, but it needs to save it in the historical database. However, if we have a connection error with the historical database, we need to also send an alarm.

Is this really a circular reference, where main has alarm but alarm also has main and the same for database/main? How would you solve it?

Comment: It looks like a design flaw, can you elaborate on the classes, and what they are supposed to do? Maybe we will be able to come up with a different design

Comment: How to solve marriage OO? I love the question! I am sure that there are many (academic) solutions, but I would (pragmatic) have a base class for both event and alarm.

Comment: @BartlomiejLewandowski 'design flaw' or knot in the brain, you are right with "there is a need to go some steps back", i think

Comment: I have posted by solution in the answer. More than 10 years have passed since I am obsessed with this question but I still interested in the solution of this curios and seemingly ubequitous probelm.

Comment: I changed the code. Before it was event manager and now, for better understanding, I use a database manager. I hope now you get the idea. The thing is i have many of these so called 'managers' interconnected and I have no clue on how to decouple them to avoid a circular reference.

Comment: In the new edition, the issue basically is how to write "cannot write into the log" message into the log? It rankles me even longer. It seems more causality question now rather than OOP. I would filter impossible messages somehow. I would ask at programmers.SE since it is quite conceptual.

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar problem when did a CAD development. In every Electronic CAD you have some component ports and signal lines that represent connections between the ports. The lines and ports are many-to-many connections: every line must maintain a list of ports that it binds together as well as the ports must beware of the lines, attached to them. So, every time user wants to connect two ports, he creates a line and attaches the line to each port by

```
line.add(port)
port.add(line)
```

These two operations must always be executed together. This means they must be abstracted as a procedure: calling `line.add(port)` would automatically call `port.add(line)` and, by symmetry, `port.add(line)` should call `line.add(port)`. Well, we are in the vicious circle, exactly the one you have in your question!

I bothered me for years but I did nothing better than giving up the symmetry. I have exposed only `line.add` to the user, hiding the `port.add`, that it calls, behind my netlist manipulation API. This way, `port.add` does not need to call the `line.add` back since we know that we are in `port.add` only because `line.add` is already happening.

I could restore the symmetry by introducing public `port.add` and `line.add`, which would call API-private `line.onAdd(port)` and `port.onAdd(line)` callbacks. This also seems trivial. Yet, you are right asking this question. I encourage you to upvote my response but not accept it. I would like to know the correct (OOP) answer myself.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
MyMain() {
    alarmManager = new AlarmManager();
    databaseManager = new DatabaseManager();
    alarmManager.setDatabaseManager(databaseManager);
    databaseManager.setAlarmManager(alarmManager);
}
```

Your alarmManager class has a setDatabaseManager method.

Your databaseManager class has a setAlarmManager method.

Answer (score 0):

Gilbert has one good approach, but an alternative is to have both alarmManager and databaseManager have a reference to `MyMain` *instead* of each other.  *e.g.*

```
AlarmManager {
    MyMain myMain;  // set in the constructor, could be final

    onAlarm(alarm) {
        myMain.getDataBaseManager().saveInHistorical(alarm);
        sendAlarm(alarm);
    }

    sendAlarm(alarm) {
        socketWriter(alarm);
    }
}

DatabaseManager{
    MyMain myMain;  // set in the constructor, could be final

    onDatabaseConnectionError() {
        saveInHistorical(databaseAlarm);
        myMain.getAlarmManager().sendAlarm(databaseAlarm);
    }

    saveInHistorical(historical) {
        connection.store(historical);
    }
}
```

1. Advantage: no setters required, your classes can be immutable.
2. Advantage: Simple and pragmatic.
3. Disadvantage that might be an Advantage: Greater coupling.  In the future, when you add a FooManager and a BarManager that AlarmManager  and DatabaseManager need, they can also be in MyMain, simplifying your life immensely.  However, this definitely adds coupling and "globalness" so too much of this would be a bad thing.  If you go beyond "simple and pragmatic" to "here is the Kitchen Sink" you should stop and rethink.
4. Disadvantage that I don't care about cause I think it's a poor law: violates Law of Demeter. But its easily modifiable to avoid this if you really care.